# Upgrade TinyMCE to V4 on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tinymce

I've looking this solution for hours! 
The v3 is way to old and buggy. 
Anyone has been able to upgrade it to v4.3?

Comment: Old? Probably by version. Buggy? What is buggy? Can you share  examples where v3 actually is an issue while v4.3 would be not?  And finally, what hinders you to use it in parallel and require.js it where you need it? And looking for the solution for hours: Which concepts did you follow, what has already proven for you non-working? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks! I mean, that v3 is old, and I can't find for example Youtube plugins that work with the new Youtube embed iframe way.

Comment: And what have you tried so far,. what was the outcome and how is the outcome insufficient to what you'd like to do? If you give the question more substance, it's easier for others to provide more valuable feed or even an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to upgrade any component of magento.
Magento 2 has some plugins for tinymce that might not work on version 4.

Comment: I agree with @Marius, Magento probably has a good reason that it still uses an older version of TinyMCE. Could also possibly be a remnant of much of the ported code of Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a module which upgrades the editor to TinyMCE 4 and also covers the customized plugins (widgets, variables, images), currently working for Magento 2.1 and 2.2.

For those who want to check it out:
https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4

Comment: Good stuff, do you have a spell checker in the module as plugin?